# Trying to fix a stack overflow error in my code

Tags: java, arrays, stack-overflow

What I'm trying to do is make a class that handles a deck of cards as defined by the Card class. To make it easier on myself, I made the parameters both be integers and then I made 2 separate (and private) toString methods to give the String equivalent of the value. The issue is, it's giving me a Stack overflow error when I try to run my test class. Here is my work so far:

(I know I can use a switch statement if I wanted to, but I don't have a firm grasp of them and I don't want to do something wrong).

Card Class:

```
public class Card {

private int cardNumber;
private int cardSuit;
private Card cardCard;

public Card(int cardNumber, int cardSuit){

    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
    cardCard = new Card(cardNumber, cardSuit);

}


public String dealCard(){

    return ("The card is the " + cardCard.toStringCardNumber() + " of " + cardCard.toStringCardSuit() + ".");

}

private String toStringCardNumber(){

    if(cardNumber == 1){

        return ("Ace");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 2){

        return ("2");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 3){

        return ("3");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 4){

        return ("4");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 5){

        return ("5");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 6){

        return ("6");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 7){

        return ("7");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 8){

        return ("8");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 9){

        return ("9");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 10){

        return ("10");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 11){

        return ("Jack");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 12){

        return ("Queen");

    }

    else if(cardNumber == 13){

        return ("King");

    }

    return null;

}

private String toStringCardSuit(){

    if(cardSuit == 1){

        return ("Diamonds");

    }

    else if(cardSuit == 2){

        return ("Hearts");

    }

    else if(cardSuit == 3){

        return ("Clubs");

    }

    else if(cardSuit == 4){

        return ("Spades.");

    }

    return null;

}


}
```

Deck of Cards Class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards {

public DeckOfCards(){

    Card deckOfCardsArray[] = new Card[52];

}

public void createDeck(){

    for(int i = 1; i < 53; i++){

        if(i < 14){

            deckOfCardsArray[i] = new Card(i, 1);

        }

        else if(i >= 14 && i < 27){

            deckOfCardsArray[i] = new Card(i - 13, 2);

        }

        else if(i >= 27 && i < 40){

            deckOfCardsArray[i] = new Card(i - 26, 3);

        }

        else if(i >= 40 && i < 54){

            deckOfCardsArray[i] = new Card(i - 39, 4);

        }

    }

}


public void shuffleDeck(){

    Card tempCard1 = new Card(0, 0);
    int tempInt = deckOfCardsRandom.nextInt(53);

    for(int i = 0; i < 53; i++){

        tempCard1 = deckOfCardsArray[i];

        deckOfCardsArray[i] = deckOfCardsArray[tempInt + i];

        deckOfCardsArray[tempInt + i] = tempCard1;

    }

}

public String dealCard(int i){

    cardsRemaining--;

    return deckOfCardsArray[i].dealCard();

}

public int getCardsRemaining(){

    return cardsRemaining;

}

private Card[] deckOfCardsArray;
private int cardsRemaining = 52;
private Random deckOfCardsRandom;

}
```

Test class:

```
public class DeckOfCardsTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    DeckOfCards deckie = new DeckOfCards();

    deckie.createDeck();

    System.out.println(deckie.dealCard(5));

    System.out.println(deckie.getCardsRemaining());


}

}
```

The specific error is: http://pastie.org/8493772

Any ideas as to what is causing the problem?

Comment: A card creates a card that creates a card...Rethink your logic.

Comment: Well in that case, how would I make it so that the object can be created safely? Otherwise, the toString methods wouldn't work properly.

Comment: Why do you think you need this line `cardCard = new Card(cardNumber, cardSuit);`? Your object is already a `Card`. Why do you need a reference to another `Card`?

Comment: Wouldn't I not be able to use the toString methods otherwise?

Comment: Just use `this` card's attributes.

Comment: But then where would I define the method to change the integer value of the face or the suit to a String?

Comment: Same as you have it now.

Comment: Actually, I see what you're saying, but could you write that in code so I can understand how to use that?

Comment: You might find that `enum`s work better than `int`s for holding your card suits and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this line from your constructor:

```
cardCard = new Card(cardNumber, cardSuit);
```

Every time you create a `Card`, it will create a new `Card`, which create another one, etc. This continues until you run out of stack-space and get a stack overflow.

You don't need the `cardCard` field in the class.

---

Furthermore, a switch case for your `toStringCardNumber` method, would look like this:

```
switch (cardNumber) {
    case 1:
        return "Ace";
    case 2: 
        return "2";
    case 3:
        return "3";

    //... Put the remaining cases here

    default:
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your Card class you are instantiating an additional identical Card object.

You do not appear to be referencing the internal copy of the Card object for anything you could not do without it so just remove that line and you should be fine.

The reason this is causing an issue is because it is forming a loop where every card created causes another card to be created until you are so deep creating so many cards that you overflow the stack.

You appear to be using the internal 'cardCard' object to call functions that could be called on the parent card, just replace 'cardCard' with 'this' or call the functions directly as in 'toStringCardNumber()' instead of 'cardCard.toStringCardNumber()'.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you're creating a Card in some other class, like so:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int rank = 2;
        int rank = 6;
        Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
    }
}
```

Now, in your Card class, you attempt to make another Card object when MyOtherClass already instantiated it, so you're getting a cascading effect where a single attempt to instantiate Card generates infinite new Cards until you blow up your stack.

```
public Card(int cardNumber, int cardSuit){

    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
    // This line is dangerously redundant. Don't do this. Ever.
    cardCard = new Card(cardNumber, cardSuit);

}
```

Your toString() should run something like this:

```
public class Card
{
    // whatever code you already have

    public String toString()
    {
        String cardName = "";

        if(suit == 1)
        {
            if(cardNumber == 1)
            {
                cardName = "Ace of Spades";
            }
            else if(cardNumber == 2)
            {
                cardName = "Two of Spades";
            }
            // And so on... I think you get the idea
        }
        else if(suit == 2)
        {
        }
```

I really encourage you to go over your Java learning materials and try to get a better handle on how to create and use Java Objects. It seems that something has eluded your understanding at the moment, but a bit more work and I think you'll be able to wrap your mind around the concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Card(int cardNumber, int cardSuit){

this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
cardCard = new Card(cardNumber, cardSuit);
```

}

This will go on forever (recursive).

Remove

```
cardCard = new Card(cardNumber, cardSuit);
```

and where you declare your variable.

```
private Card cardCard;
```

In your deckOfCards class is where you create your `Card` object - that where your create it and reference it. You do not need to create a `Card` object inside another `Card` object - you never reference this anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You need to stop dealing cards when there's no more cards to deal.

```
public String dealCard(int i){

    cardsRemaining--;

    if(cardsRemaining >= 0) {
        return deckOfCardsArray[i].dealCard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, didn't notice that. Not the error, but thanks anyways!